# back4app | Flutter - How to update _User with id?

Tags: flutter, back4app

How to edit user's username and password?

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
var user = ParseObject('User')..objectId = 'ifBuLmgxQ5'..set('username', username);
await user.save();
```

```
I/flutter ( 7364):  https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/User/ifBuLmgxQ5
I/flutter ( 7364): ╰--
I/flutter ( 7364): ╭-- Parse Response
I/flutter ( 7364): Class: User
I/flutter ( 7364): Function: ParseApiRQ.save
I/flutter ( 7364): Status Code: 101
I/flutter ( 7364): Type: ObjectNotFound
I/flutter ( 7364): Error: Object not found.
I/flutter ( 7364): ╰--
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_User` as a class name.

So, it should look like this:

```
var user = ParseObject('_User')..objectId = 'ifBuLmgxQ5'..set('username', username);

await user.save();
```